# F#: how to use "with" constructor for more values

Tags: constructor, f#, with-statement

In F# I can do:

```
let card = { anotherCard with Cost = 4 }
```

But I want to do:

```
let card = { anotherCard with Cost = 4 with WinPoints = 5 }
```

or at least have some one liner, right now I have to:

```
let cardTemp = { anotherCard with Cost = 4 }
let card = { cardTemp with WinPoints = 5 }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can separate multiple field setters with semicolons:

```
let card = { anotherCard with Cost = 4; WinPoints = 5 }
```

You can also put the fields on separate lines (without semicolon delimiters):

```
let card = { anotherCard with
                Cost = 4
                WinPoints = 5 }
```

Comment: As a general note, semicolons in lists can also be omitted if you put the items on separate lines. `[1; 2; 3]` on one line needs semicolons, but `[1\n 2\n 3]` (if we pretend those `\n` markers are actual newlines in your code) is also a valid way to write a list of three ints.

Comment: ... with the condition that you put all the items at the same indentation level.